# php array select element depended on other array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array for weeks days like this

```
$daysNumber=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

I need to convert it to names like this

```
$daysName = array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday','saturday');
```

the days numbers it's dynamic 
the user selects them and i get the array for example like this
(1,3,4) i want to replace each number with the day name like this (Sunday,Tuesday,wednesday)

what is the best option to convert it

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the `$daysNumber` variable and start the `$daysName` at 1 rather than 0.

You can then use `array_key_intersect()` and `array_flip()` to extract the days you are after...

```
$daysName = array( 1=> 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday','saturday');

$selected = [1,3,4];

print_r(array_intersect_key($daysName, array_flip($selected)));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [1] => sunday
    [3] => tuesday
    [4] => wednesday
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `$daysName` is enough:

```
$daysName = array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday','saturday');
```

As it is zero-indexed, its indexes correspond to your `$daysNumber` as `index - 1`.

So for `1,3,4` you output:

```
$daysName[0];  // 1 - 1
$daysName[2];  // 3 - 1
$daysName[3];  // 4 - 1
```

But if you still need you can reindex your `$daysName` starting from 1:

```
$daysName = array(1 => 'sunday', 2 => 'monday', 3 => 'tuesday'); // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `date` with `array_map`

```
$alphaDays = array_map(function($d){
    $d--;
    return date('l', strtotime("Sunday + $d Days"));
}, $days);
print_r($alphaDays);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/aCDRh